# Can't use constructor passed as function argument in CoffeeScript?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Edited with more context. When $CONSTRUCTOR = passed_in, it throws "passed_in is not a constructor" in Firefox and Chrome. When $CONSTRUCTOR = not_passed_in, it does not

```
  initialize: (options) ->
    @collection.bind 'all', @render
    $('.search_box').parent('form').submit (event) => 
      @loading()
      event.preventDefault()
      query = $(event.target).find('.search_box').val()
      window.app.navigate('?query=' + query, trigger: true)
    passed_in = PaginationView
    @render(passed_in)

  render: (passed_in)=> 
    if @collection.isEmpty() && @collection.query
      @$el.html(JST['users/no_results'](query: @collection.query))
    else if @collection.isEmpty() # Not loaded yet
      @$el.html("<div class='loading'></div>")
    else
      html = JST['users/user_list'](@viewData())
      @$el.html(html)
      for user in @collection.models
        html = new UserListItemView(model: user).render().el
        @$('tbody.users').append(html)

      not_passed_in = PaginationView
      new $CONSTRUCTOR(
        type: "user"
        el: @$('.paginate')
        model: @collection
        data: {}
        onError: @onError
      ).bind('change', @loading)
```

Is this a known (bug|feature) of CoffeeScript? Or am I doing something wrong?

(These are in Backbone.coffee views. I doubt that's relevant)

Comment: I suspect there's something else going on, as I can't repro this. Could you post a more elaborate code sample?

Comment: I can't reproduce this type of error either. I modified a view in one of my Backbone apps so that `intialize` passed a class type to `render`, which then creates an instance of said class, and it works fine

Comment: Which version of the coffee script compiler are you using? Works fine with 1.3.3

Comment: Wouldn't it be the easiest to look at the compiled javascript?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the problem:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend

    initialize: (options) ->
        passed_in = PaginationView
        @render(passed_in)

    render: (passed_in) => 
          not_passed_in = PaginationView
          new passed_in(
            type: "user"
            el: @$('.paginate')
            model: @collection
            data: {}
            onError: @onError
          ).bind('change', @loading)
```

1) Usually the last line of @render is `@` or `this` rather than another view.

2) **Most likely problem** is that there is some other code which is calling `@render()` with no arguments. Suggest you give a default argument like:

```
render: (passed_in=PaginationView) =>
```

3) If `PaginationView` creates a `MyView`, you could get a stack overflow error:

- MyView.initialize calls render,
- calls PaginationView.initialize
- calls MyView.initialize
- .. loop.

4) Is JSON.stringify getting called on `passed_in` at any point? If so, it will convert the function into `undefined`:

```
passed_in = JSON.stringify(passed_in)
undefined == passed_in
# always true if passed_in is a function
```